# Adding Admob to flutter App causes it to crash on startup

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob

I am trying to add Admob to a flutter app. 
I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXYmbTBT3Yo
as well as the official documentation for the plugin:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_admob

I added these lines to my app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="ca-app-pub-#~#" />
```

Replacing the #~# I copied from the add app ui in the AdMob page.
I also added this dependency in the `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
firebase_admob: ^0.9.0+1
```

But when I load the app, it gets to:

```
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
```

The app flashes on the screen and closes. I also couldn't find any way of showing the error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you will have solved that problem yet. If no, then changing the version of firebase_admob in pubspec.yaml file to 0.5.3 will solve your problem inshaAllah. Just change the version from 0.9.0+1 to 0.5.3